# Why is my expansion tile expanding to the whole screen

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to call an api when I expand the tile by using future builder. Which returns a list. However, when I click on it, it expands the whole screen and doesn't display anything.

Here's an image of what I'm describing: 
[image: Expansion tile just got expanded]

[image: Without expanded]

Here's the code:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: marketApiCall(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int count) {
                return ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[count].itemName),
                  children: <Widget>[
                     FutureBuilder(
                        future: getItemDetail(itemName: snapshot.data[count].urlName),
                        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
                          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData){
                              debug.output(fromFunction:"Widget build", message: snapshot.data[0]['en']['description']);
                              return Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text("Item description: ", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Text(snapshot.data[0]['en']['description'].toString().replaceAll(reg, ''))
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )                                  
                              );
                            } else {
                              return Center(
                                child: Text("Error: No data")
                              );
                            }           
                          } else {
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      )
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text("There was an error with the api call, please try again later")             
            );
          }
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

I've tried adding shrinkwrap to see if that would work. That didn't.
Also, debug.output is just a custom function that displays print messages so there is no need to worry about that. As you can see, it's a future builder inside a futurebuilder. I've tried separating the inside future builder to a separate stateful class and returning a column to the expansion tile, however that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proble is right after the "FutureBuilder"

```
return Container(
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
```

You're giving its child Container an 80% of the screen height, that, with the ExpansionTile's height, will occupy the whole screen (or almost).
Try removing the container height and let its child to size the container.

Comment: This does sound quite likely, thank you for spotting it. I'll go ahead and try to implement what you suggested